# ODBC call to CHARINDEX returning "Invalid Column Name"

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010

Using Access 2010 to run a pass-through query against SQL Server.  Query is as follows:

```
select da.o_acttime,ds.o_statename,dd.o_filename,dd.o_projectno from dms_audt da
inner join
dms_doc dd
on
da.o_objguid=dd.o_docguid
left join
dms_stat ds
on
ds.o_stateno=da.o_numparam2
where
da.o_action=1012
and
charindex(".xls",dd.o_filename)>0
order by o_projectno
```

The error message I get in response is:

```
ODBC--call failed.
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name '.xls'. (#207)
```

Am I calling `charindex()` incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it.  ".xls" should be in single quotes instead, as '.xls'.

Comment: Someone just edited this to add: "Also, charindex takes a single character. You probably want patindex('%.xls%', dd.o_filename)."  Which is useful, but it should be its own answer or a comment on my answer, not a change to my answer's content.